# How can I update customer custom attribute on order save?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, magento2.2.0

I have an observer for the event when an order is placed by a customer.
I tried "sales_model_service_quote_submit_before"

I would like to take a value from the Order and save it to the customer.

For example.

```php
$customer = $quote->getCustomer();
if ($customer) {
  $customer->setData('someValue', $quote->getData('someValue')))
  $customer->save();
}
```

I have also tried

```php
$customerId = $quote->getCustomerId();
if ($customerId) {
  $customer = $customerRepository->getById($customerId);
  $customer->setSomeValue('1234');
  $customer->save();
}
```

Can someone please provide an example of an observer to do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try This :-**

```
protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
) {
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
}

public function execute()
{
    $customerId = 2; // Corresponding customer id
    $customer = $this->_customerFactory->create()->load($customerId)->getDataModel();
    $customer->setCustomAttribute('custom_attribute_name', 'value');
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->save($customer);
}
```

Comment: Worked for me thank you :)

Comment: Most Welcome...